# Get all height at listview with custom adapter and scrollview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I'd like to use `listview` with custom adapter and it dynamically changing.
There is that i want (element above `ListView` must be scrolled):

[image]

I found two main ways to do it:

- use `ScrollView` and code with `listView.measure(0,0);` to dynamically set up the `listview` height (but it doesn't work, listview is cropped);
  For example: listView have 3 items, but it height is for 2 items (1 item is hidden);

[image]

- don't use `ScrollView`, use a `setHeaderView` (but it doesn't work too, `ListView` don't have a scrolling)
  [image]

Any idea?

Comment: Can u frame the question again? There is lot of confusion to the title and the content.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your listview doesnt have the correct height? example, it has the height of 2 items, while there are 3 in it? And I assume the scrollview is inside the listview with custom adapter?

Comment: Yes, listView doesn't have the correct height.
I try to use two ways: 
- listview in scrollview;
- listview with setHeaderView function

Comment: I hate to ask nagging annoying questions, but if I understand correctly you'd want to have a listView containing, TextView, H-ListView, TextView, Button and your custom adapter-ed Listview? And if you would scroll you'd scroll the entire layout, and not just the custom adapter-ed ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom ListView **ExpandableHeightListView** here

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.widget.ListView;

      public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
    {

    boolean expanded = false;

        public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
     {
     super(context);
    }

      public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
       {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

      public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

use

```
 list.setExpanded(true);
```

in onCreate() method.

Comment: Your welcome. But i got this idea from some other post. But unfortunately i dont know that link.

Answer (score 0):

i have a fragment in one of my apps who looks pretty much the same..
and I had the same problem as you, what I did in my case was set up the size for each of my list view cells at a fixed size. and measure the height by that logic.

not sure if that's considered the best way to achieve that, but it worked for me.

```
filterListView.getLayoutParams().height = (searchLabelsList.size() * (int) (43 * getScale() + 0.5f)) + (filterListView.getDividerHeight() * (searchLabelsList.size() - 1));

                            filterListView.setAdapter(searchLabelsAdapter);
```

and in the formula, 43 is the height for each cell, in dp's of course.

getScale is a method I wrote to get the scale of the screen size of the current user phone:

```
private float scale;

private float getScale() {
    if (scale == 0) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            scale = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        }
    }
    return scale;
}
```

hope this will help, any question feel free to ask :)

good luck

Comment: I think it works for adapter layout with fixed size.
But my adapter layout have a TextView with height = "wrap_content"

Comment: my textview is also wrap_content, try using it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First : In your xml put all other views inside ScrollView including ListView

```
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" >             

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                // Add your other views over here....

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Second : In your java file,

```
     Just use this custom method setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview)
```

How ??

```
      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
      list.setAdapter(YOUR CUSTOM ADAPTER);
      setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);
```

Here is your custom method.

```
        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) 
{
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight=0;
    View view = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);

        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,  
                                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + ((listView.getDividerHeight()) * (listAdapter.getCount()));

    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Try and let me know, and sorry if i misunderstood your question.